# Array output for option of command in bash script

Tags: bash, encoding, attachment, mkv

I'm stuck figure out with my bash script with array for option of command.

I make bash script to extract attachments from mkv file, and at the end merge again that attachments to mkv file after the video/audio has been encoding.

This is for extract attachment

```
#find the total of attachment
A=$(mkvmerge -i input.mkv | grep -i attachment 
                          | awk '{printf $3 "\n"}' 
                          | sed 's;\:;;' 
                          | awk 'END { print NR }')

#extract it
for (( i=1; i<=$A; i++ ))
do
font[${i}]="$(mkvmerge -i input.mkv | grep -i attachment 
                                    | awk '{for (i=11; i <= NF; i++) printf($i"%c" , (i==NF)?ORS:OFS) }' 
                                    | sed "s/'//g" 
                                    | awk "NR==$i")"

mkvextract attachments input.mkv $i:"${font[${i}]}"
done
```

And now for merge again the attachment

```
for (( i=1; i<=$A; i++ ))
do
#seach for space between file name and and '\' before 
#the space because some attachment has space in filename
font1[${i}]=$(echo ${font[${i}]} | sed 's/ /\\ /g')
#make option for add attachment
attachment[${i}]=$"--attach-file ${font1[${i}]}"
done

mkvmerge -o output.mkv -d 1 -S test.mp4 sub.ass ${attachment[*]}
```

The problem, still can't work for file name with space.
When I tried echo the `${attachment[*]}`, it seem all right

```
--attach-file Beach.ttf --attach-file Candara.ttf 
                        --attach-file CASUCM.TTF 
                        --attach-file Complete\ in\ Him.ttf 
                        --attach-file CURLZ_.TTF 
                        --attach-file Frostys\ Winterland.TTF 
                        --attach-file stilltim.ttf
```

But the output still recognize the file name with space only the first word.

```
mkvmerge v3.0.0 ('Hang up your Hang-Ups') built on Dec  6 2010 19:19:04
Automatic MIME type recognition for 'Beach.ttf': application/x-truetype-font
Automatic MIME type recognition for 'Candara.ttf': application/x-truetype-font
Automatic MIME type recognition for 'CASUCM.TTF': application/x-truetype-font
Error: The file 'Complete\' cannot be attached because it does not exist or cannot be read.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignacio's answer will point you in the right direction, but I wanted to comment on some things in your script.

This line has a lot of pointless gyrations:

```
A=$(mkvmerge -i input.mkv | grep -i attachment | awk '{printf $3 "\n"}' | sed 's;\:;;' | awk 'END { print NR }')
```

Here it is simplified:

```
A=$(mkvmerge -i input.mkv | grep -i attachment | wc -l)
```

It's not necessary to use a dollar sign and braces for array indices:

```
attachment[i]="--attach-file ${font1[i]}"
```

Also, `$""` is used for creating strings for translation (i18n and l10n). You probably don't need it there. However, this is one of the lines that you should change because it's part of your problem. You will find that the line prior to this one with the `sed` command will be unnecessary.

**Edit:**

If you really need to use an array:

```
for (( i=1; i<=A; i++ ))
do
    #make option for add attachment
    attachment+=("--attach-file" "${font1[i]}")
done

mkvmerge -o output.mkv -d 1 -S test.mp4 sub.ass "${attachment[@]}"
```

The resulting `attachment` array will have twice as many elements as the `font1` array.

```
$ declare -p font1 attachment    # show the contents
declare -a font1='([0]="Beach.ttf" [1]="Candara.ttf" [2]="CASUCM.TTF" [3]="Complete" [4]="in" [5]="Him.ttf" [6]="CURLZ_.TTF" [7]="Frostys" [8]="Winterland.TTF" [9]="stilltim.ttf")'
declare -a attachment='([0]="--attach-file" [1]="Beach.ttf" [2]="--attach-file" [3]="Candara.ttf" [4]="--attach-file" [5]="CASUCM.TTF" [6]="--attach-file" [7]="Complete in Him.ttf" [8]="--attach-file" [9]="CURLZ_.TTF" [10]="--attach-file" [11]="Frostys Winterland.TTF" [12]="--attach-file" [13]="stilltim.ttf")'
```

Comment: thanks for simplified the script, but for A=$(mkvmerge -i input.mkv | wc -l), you're missing grep -i attachment, the complete line should be A=$(mkvmerge -i input.mkv | grep -i attachment | wc -l)

Comment: @dewaforex: Oops, sorry about that. I got overzealous.

Comment: No, problem. It's more simple now, but still can't figure out the last error when put double qoute at "${attachment[*]}" that was pointing by Ignacio's answer

Comment: @dewaforex: If you *really* need to have all that in an array, then you need to keep it as an array (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks your code is working... ^_^ really nobe with array me in here